# Where can i find values for variable parameters of jinja template of hadoop-env obtained using ambari api?

Tags: apache-spark, ambari, jinjava

I am working with ambari api to fetch config files for different services. But, the ambari api results in jinja template for many files( like hadoop-env, hive-env etc. ). I need to replace values for variable parameters in jinja template in order to have final config files. I have learned that params.py and params_linux.py scripts are responsible to replace these variables. But, i wonder if we can have these scripts using ambari api.

Are there alternative ways to achieve the above goal programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the answer is no.
Python files for services sometimes contain lots of logic that affects variable values.